# AngularJS ng-grid -> afterSelectionChange triggers twice

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have within ng-grid options:

```
afterSelectionChange: function (row, event) {
                console.log("Event: " + event);
                console.log("Row: " + row.rowIndex);
            },
```

The first time a row is selected, it works as expected.  The second time, it triggers twice, once for the row leaving, and again for the new row.  This is fine.  The issue is, I want to take action once, for the new row.  The only way I can do that is by examining the event.  However the event is undefined.

Output:

```
Event: undefined activityGridController.js:13
Row: 0 activityGridController.js:14
Event: undefined activityGridController.js:13
Row: 1
```

Question is, how to determine the new row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just set an extra property with the beforeSelectionChange event.
Something like this

```
beforeSelectionChange: function(row) {
  row.changed = true;
  return true;
},
afterSelectionChange: function (row, event) {
  if (row.changed){
    console.log("deal with row " + row.rowIndex);
    row.changed=false;
  }
},
```

Comment: Excellent solution! I'm impressed it only has 7 upvotes. Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

check the row.selected 
the first row should be false and the send row should be true.

```
  if(row && row.entity){
    if(row.selected){
       var selectedEntity = row.entity;
    }
  }
```